# How to delete all rows matching a condition using SqlModel

Tags: python, sqlmodel

The documentation of SqlModel about DELETE action: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/delete/

shows how to delete a single line using the functions

- .one() - If only a single record is expected

or

- .first() - to get the 1st line from multiple lines found.

```
def delete_heroes():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Hero).where(Hero.name == "Spider-Youngster")
        results = session.exec(statement)
        hero = results.one()
        print("Hero: ", hero)

        session.delete(hero)
        session.commit()
```

But how can I delete all the lines matching the condition? I tried using the .all() function

```
def delete_heroes():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Hero).where(Hero.name == "Spider-Youngster")
        results = session.exec(statement)
        hero = results.all()
        print("Hero: ", hero)

        session.delete(hero)
        session.commit()
```

But all I get is an error:
`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped`

---

My solution uses a loop to iterate over multiple lines, delete each line and commit at the end.

```
def delete_heroes():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Hero).where(Hero.name == "Spider-Youngster")
        results = session.exec(statement)
        hero = results.all()
        print("Hero: ", hero)

        for result in results:
            session.delete(result)

        session.commit()
```

**Is there a way to do this without the loop?**

Comment: Did you try without executing the `results.all()` statement? I have not found the use of `all` method in the tutorials section: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/tree/main/docs_src/tutorial/delete

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, by using directly `sqlalchemy`, on which `sqlmodel` is built:

```py
from sqlalchemy import delete
with Session(engine) as session:
    statement = delete(Hero).where(<your conditon to get several rows>)
    session.exec(statement)
    session.commit()
```